# Translate language of magento to another language- Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I m new in Magento.I want to change the English language of Magento to Persian. I cant find the good source for translating the language of Magento to another languages.can you give me a good source??

Answer (score 0):

> **Below  is the language pack for Persian language along with its details steps how to configure it for magento 2.**

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-persian-language-pack.

> **If you wanted to know about Magento 2 Translation Concepts then refer below link :**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html